# Adsense value per click

Tags: google-adsense

On my website, I have seen a significantly decline in revenue from adsense in recent weeks. My amount of clicks is the same as prior months, but the payout is way less. Does anyone know or can direct me to how google determines the payout per click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the number of advertisers bidding for website with content like yours. The more they believe/see that your site attracts the kind of customer they are looking for, the more they will put money on it (and the higher the payout per click).

Comment: True! but it can be because of the country tiers. Google is splitting countries into tiers. The higher tier users visit your website higher is CPM and CPC